# Bpy: Add a modifier to every object in the scene that doesn't yet have one

Tags: python, scripting

I would like to add specific modifiers to every object that doesn't have one yet. Below is what I have so far. I think my main limitation right now is I don't know how to find the context that also works with identifying modifiers.

```
obj = bpy.context.object
    for modifier in obj.modifiers:
        if modifier.type == "BEVEL":
            mod = obj.modifiers.new("Bevel", 'BEVEL')
            mod.limit_method='WEIGHT'
            print('kay')
        if modifier.type == "WEIGHTED_NORMAL":
            mod = obj.modifiers.new('Weighted Normal', 'WEIGHTED_NORMAL')
            mod.keep_sharp=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're looping over EXISTING modifiers and checking if they are of the correct type.

You can make use of the barely used `for ... else` idiom to do what you're looking for.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.collection.all_objects:
    if obj.type != "MESH":
        continue
    for mod in obj.modifiers:
        if mod.type == "BEVEL":  # Select the bevel modifier
            break
    else:
        mod = obj.modifiers.new("Bevel", 'BEVEL')
    mod.limit_method = 'WEIGHT'

    for mod in obj.modifiers:
        if mod.type == "WEIGHTED_NORMAL":  # Select the weighted normal modifier
            break
    else:
        mod = obj.modifiers.new('Weighted Normal', 'WEIGHTED_NORMAL')
    mod.keep_sharp = True
```

[Further reading on for ... else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970/7092409)

Another way to write it using `or`

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.collection.all_objects:
    if obj.type != "MESH":
        continue
    mod_bevel = next((m for m in obj.modifiers if m.type == "BEVEL"), None) or obj.modifiers.new("Bevel", 'BEVEL')
    mod_bevel.limit_method = 'WEIGHT'
    
    mod_weighted_normal = next((m for m in obj.modifiers if m.type == "WEIGHTED_NORMAL"), None) or obj.modifiers.new("Weighted Normal", 'WEIGHTED_NORMAL')
    mod_weighted_normal.keep_sharp = True
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!